Importing assets/images from packages in a pnpm workspace setup to nuxt 3 app using nuxt kit
I have a monorepo setup using pnpm workspace. The directory looks like:
- root
  - packages
    - my-package
      - lib
        - components
        - assets/images/*
  - apps
    - website-1
    - website-2

My issue is that I want to put all the images in the my-package/lib/assets/images/* so that website-1 and website-2 could share them without having to put 2 copies of the image for each website.
My idea is to use addImportsDir method, here's my setup:
import { addPlugin, addImportsDir, defineNuxtModule, createResolver } from '@nuxt/kit';

export default defineNuxtModule({
  setup(_, nuxt) {
    
    const { resolve } = createResolver(import.meta.url);
    
    nuxt.hook('components:dirs', dirs => {
      dirs.push({
        path: resolve('lib/components'),
        prefix: 'pz',
      });
    });

    addImportsDir(resolve('lib/assets'));
    
    // add the helper plugin
    addPlugin(resolve('lib/plugins/helper.js'));
  },
});

My nuxt config:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: ['my-package'],
  devtools: { enabled: true },
});


However, when I am trying to use the image like so:
<img src="~/assets/images/somepic.jpg" width="100" alt="">

I am getting

Failed to resolve import "assets/images/somepic.jpg" from "app.vue". Does the file exist?

I am sure the file exists in the proper location. What did I miss? Thanks
